# jenkins global credentials error on MacBook

Tags: jenkins

[the credentials page, note that the scope isn't available for selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJeji.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/getDt.jpg)

hello guys am relatively new to the information technology world, particularly to CICD, I  am not able to add jenkins  global credentials on my local machine I keep getting that same error, but I can add it using another device just not mine any ideas for a fix ?

Comment: Do you see any backend error logs?

Comment: no error logs, I am able to add global credentials from any other device just not my MacBook,